# Compress Image in iOS 12. How will this code be updated?

Tags: swift, uiimage, ios12

```
// compressing image(avaImg)before sending it to the server(Parse)

let avaData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(avaImg.image!, 0.5)
    let avaFile = PFFile(name: "ava.jpg", data: avaData!)
    user["ava"] = avaFile
```

When I replace it to the following line as recommended by the notifications I get the error below

```
let avaData = UIImage.jpegData(avaImg.image!, 0.5)
```

*ERROR: Instance member 'jpegData' cannot be used on type 'UIImage'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?*

I'm a newbie and I followed that on an online course so please baby steps!

Comment: let avaData = avaImg.image!.jpegData(avaImg.image!, 0.5)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean swift 4.2?
Call it like this `yourImageObject.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)` because function changed to `public func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?` For more syntax I have a repo you can take a reference with changes from swift 4. https://github.com/alexliubj/Swift-Migration-4.2

Updated: 
This API change is from iOS 12, not Swift 4.2. Thanks @rmaddy for your correction.

Comment: This API change is from iOS 12, not Swift 4.2.